# Работа со звуком в Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

подскажите инструменты для обработки звука в Windows Phone, нужно записать звук (голос, речь и т.п) и посмотреть по всевозможным характеристикам: амплитуда, частота, тембр, тон и т.п

я нашел вот эти пространства имен, но они не совсем то, что мне нужно: windows.phone.speech.recognition (распознание) и windows.phone.speech.synthesis (синтезация)

СПАСИБО

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит посмотреть [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402550(v=vs.105).aspx) и выбрать то, что подходит тебе. Кажется это все доступные стандартные способы для работы с медиа файлами на WP8